# How to detect empty object?

Tags: python, object, embed

This is a generic question on how to detect if an object is empty. I declare a variable as an object:

```
description = discord.Embed()
```

Put it through a method which may or may not pass arguments to the object, i.e.:

```
def my_function(x, y, z):
    ...some code goes here...
    if x == "some variable": 
        description = discord.Embed(title="X", desc="Y + z")
        return description
    else:
        description = discord.Embed()
        return description
```

I wish to display the description only if it is not empty:

```
if description: client.send_message(message.channel, embed=description)
```

However the above code doesn't seem to work and my message gets displayed regardless of whether it is empty or otherwise. What do I do?

Comment: try this: if !description: client.send_message(message.channel, embed=description)

Comment: What does `discord.Embed()` returns ?

Comment: "Empty" object isn't well defined. Just because you don't pass any arguments doesn't mean there aren't some default values that will be used instead.

Comment: @MateusMartins Are you sure that is not a `syntax error` ?

Comment: What you probably want is to set `description = None` instead.

Comment: Why don't you add `isEmpty()` method to your object definition ?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `__bool__` method of `discord.Embed`:

```
import discord
discord.Embed.__bool__ = lambda self: bool(self.title)
```

so that the `Embed` object would be considered truthy only if it has a non-empty title, and that your code:

```
if description: client.send_message(message.channel, embed=description)
```

would work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Python's definition of `empty` (evaluates to `False`) is based on generic objects, not on whatever you have in your mind.  If you control the class (which you do not, in this case), you can add an `isEmpty` method to implement your own idea.

However, since you're using a well-established class, you need to read through the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to understand how to "ask" the right question for *your* idea of "empty".  Your variable `description` is decidedly *not* empty: it has your initialization information in the object fields, etc.  The default definition is whether the object description is `None`.

I infer from your usage that you might want to see whether there are any outstanding messages.  If so, I think you can do this with

```
if description.messages:
    client.send_message(message.channel, embed=description)
```

`messages` is a deque whose intrinsic `isEmpty` method could do what you want.